# Correct my understanding of the logical flow of the formulation of General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity

Correct and direct me when I am wrong.
That is how I understand the logical flow of the formulation of the general theory of relativity:
First we have the equivalence principle, that one tells us that if want to see the effect of gravity just figure out the Physics in some frame accelerating with g in a semi flat space . We figured out the Physics and it looked in there like if we were doing Physics in some curved surface or something. So, we conclude that including the gravitational field in any metric makes the spacetime described by that metric curved. That is why gravity is the curvature of spacetime! So, we now throw away this accelerated frame  and deal from now on with completely curved spacetime whose curvature is due the inclusion of the gravitational field in its metric and we are guaranteed to obtain the effects we hoped for  ...Is anything of what I have said right?

Comment: This is the best explanation of "what GR is" that I have seen, that doesn't require digging into the math: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNhJY-R3Gwg&ab_channel=minutephysics

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First we have the equivalence principle, that one tells us that if want to see the effect of gravity just figure out the Physics in some frame accelerating with g in a semi flat space

This is ok, except it is important to emphasize that the equivalence principle is a local principle. It only describes a small neighborhood of spacetime around some given event.

Within the local frame it explains why an accelerometer does not detect gravity: locally gravity is a fictitious force and accelerometers do not detect fictitious forces. It also means that an object with an accelerometer that reads 0, an inertial object, forms a straight line in spacetime. The parabola that a projectile makes is due to using curved coordinates, the projectile itself forms a straight line in spacetime.

> We figured out the Physics and it looked in there like if we were doing Physics in some curved surface or something.

Digging a bit deeper here is worthwhile. As mentioned above, an object with an accelerometer that reads 0 forms a straight line in spacetime. Furthermore, two objects that are at rest with respect to each other form parallel lines in spacetime.

Now, in the absence of gravity, two inertial objects that start out at rest with respect to each other remain mutually at rest. In spacetime this is the simple fact that two straight parallel lines keep the same distance and never intersect.

However, when there is tidal gravity, gravity that varies in space, you can have two objects that are initially at rest, have always 0 accelerometer readings, but eventually collide. In spacetime this implies two straight lines that are parallel at one point but intersect at another. This is impossible in a flat spacetime, but is possible in a curved spacetime.

This is why the equivalence principle implies that tidal gravity is represented by spacetime curvature.

> So, we now throw away this accelerated frame and deal from now on with completely curved spacetime whose curvature is due the inclusion of the gravitational field in its metric and we are guaranteed to obtain the effects we hoped for

We don’t have to throw away the locally accelerated frame. We have to use a coordinate-independent formulation of the laws of physics. Once we have that we can use any coordinates we like just the same. Including the accelerated coordinates.